# How to invoke a constexpr function on both device and host?

Tags: cuda

From the documentation:

> I.4.20.4. Constexpr functions and function templates
>
> By default, a
> constexpr function cannot be called from a function with incompatible
> execution space. The experimental nvcc flag --expt-relaxed-constexpr
> removes this restriction. When this flag is specified, host code can
> invoke a __device__ constexpr function and device code can invoke a
> __host__ constexpr function.

I read it, but I don't understand what it means - `device code can invoke a host constexpr function`? Here is my test:

```
constexpr int bar(int i)
{
#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__
  return i;
#else
  return 555;
#endif
}

__global__ void kernel()
{
  int tid = (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x) + threadIdx.x;

  printf("%i\n", bar(tid));
}

int main(int argc, char *[])
{
  static_assert(bar(5) > 0);
  // static_assert(bar(argc) > 0); // compile error

  cout << bar(argc) << endl;

  kernel<<<2, 2>>>();
  gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());

  gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

  return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
555
0
1
2
3
```

According to my understanding, the host invokes the *host* function, while the device invokes the *device* function. I.e. it behaves the same as if I declare `bar` with both `__host__` and `__device__` attributes. Adding a single attribute (`__host__` or `__device__`) doesn't make any difference.

As a comparison, the documentation for `std::initializer_list` is much clearer:

> I.4.20.2. std::initializer_list
>
> By default, the CUDA compiler will
> implicitly consider the member functions of std::initializer_list to
> have __host__ __device__ execution space specifiers, and therefore
> they can be invoked directly from device code.

Here I don't have any questions.

What does the documentation mean exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code.

```
#include <algorithm> //std::max

__global__ void kernel(int *array, int n) {
    array[0] = std::max(array[1], array[2]);
}
```

This code will not compile by default.

`error: calling a constexpr __host__ function("max") from a __global__ function("kernel") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.`

std::max is a standard host function without `__device__` execution space specifiers and thus cannot be called from device code.

However, when the compiler flag `--expt-relaxed-constexpr` is specified, the code compiles nonetheless. I cannot give you any details about how this is achieved internally

Comment: Your description indicates a device called a `__device__` function. My test shows that this is expected. The documentation says otherwise.

Comment: @nikitablack std::max is a host function. but since it is marked constexpr (in the standard library), it can be called as if it were a device function.